# How to Create hash from a class and selector? (objective c)

Tags: objective-c, hash

I have a dictionary that stores an object using a combination of the class name and selector as the key. I'm using the following function in order to calculate the hash:

```
+(NSString*) getKeyForClass:(Class) clazz andSelector:(SEL) selector {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@",NSStringFromClass(clazz), NSStringFromSelector(selector)];
}
```

While running a profiler i've discovered that this function is the bottleneck of the computation. Is there a better (= more efficient) way to create a key from a class and a selector?

Comment: Could you clarify? Are you using the `NSString` as a key in the dictionary, or are you using it only in the implementation of a `hash` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few alternatives.

### Keep using a string as a key, but do it faster:

Using a string is a bit more heavyweight than you really need, but it is at least simple.

Using `-[NSString stringByAppendingString]` would be faster. Parsing format strings is a lot of work.

```
return [[NSStringFromClass(clazz) stringByAppendingString:@"_"] stringByAppendingString:NSStringFromSelector(selector)];
```

It may be better to use a single `NSMutableString` instead of making intermediate strings. Profile it and see.

```
NSMutableString* result = [NSStringFromClass(clazz) mutableCopy];
[result appendString:@"_"];
[result appendString:NSStringFromSelector(selector)];
return result;
```

### Use a custom object as a key:

You can make a custom object as the key that refers to the class and selector. Implement `NSCopying` and `-isEqual:` and `-hash` on it, so you can use it as a key in a dictionary.

```
@interface MyKey : NSObject <NSCopying>
{
    Class _clazz;
    SEL _selector;
}

- (id)initWithClass:(Class)clazz andSelector:(SEL)selector;

@end

@implementation MyKey

- (id)initWithClass:(Class)clazz andSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _clazz = clazz;
        _selector = selector;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone*)zone
{
    return self; // this object is immutable, so no need to actually copy it
}

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)other
{
    if ([other isKindOfClass:[MyKey class]]) {
        MyKey* otherKey = (MyKey*)other;
        return _clazz == otherKey->_clazz && _selector == otherKey->_selector;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}

// Hash combining method from http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-06-18-implementing-equality-and-hashing.html
#define NSUINT_BIT (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(NSUInteger))
#define NSUINTROTATE(val, howmuch) ((((NSUInteger)val) << howmuch) | (((NSUInteger)val) >> (NSUINT_BIT - howmuch)))

- (NSUInteger)hash
{
    return NSUINTROTATE([_clazz hash], NSUINT_BIT / 2) ^ (NSUInteger)_selector;
}

@end

+ (MyKey*)keyForClass:(Class)clazz andSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    return [[MyKey alloc] initWithClass:clazz andSelector:selector];
}
```

### Eliminate the middleman:

If you never need to pull the class and selector out of your key object, then you can just use the hash as computed above, stored in an `NSNumber`.

```
// Hash combining method from http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-06-18-implementing-equality-and-hashing.html
#define NSUINT_BIT (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(NSUInteger))
#define NSUINTROTATE(val, howmuch) ((((NSUInteger)val) << howmuch) | (((NSUInteger)val) >> (NSUINT_BIT - howmuch)))

+ (NSNumber*)keyForClass:(Class)clazz andSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    NSUInteger hash = NSUINTROTATE([clazz hash], NSUINT_BIT / 2) ^ (NSUInteger)selector;
    return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:hash];
}
```

Comment: Edited to remove the `get` prefix.

Comment: One thing... And correct me if I'm wrong here, but doesn't NSDictionary look at the hash first when it is storing/retrieving something? (Instead of doing a bunch of isEquals first). To me that would mean you have a collision and a slowdown for any entries with the same class with the above code. One way around that would be to add the class hash to the hash of the NSStringFromSelector'd selector in the hash method.

Comment: Yes, why is why I had to implement `-hash`. The rule is: if two objects are equal, they must have the same hash. (But if two objects are *not* equal, they may still have the same hash.) I could have made `hash` return 0 every time, and it would be technically correct, although probably poor for performance. Returning just `[_clazz hash]` is easy, correct, and probably good enough. If necessary, you can do better by combining `[_clazz hash]` and the SEL. [More discussion here.](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-06-18-implementing-equality-and-hashing.html)

Comment: Also, since a SEL is a uniqued pointer, you can use its value directly instead of having to convert it to a string and then hash the string. I'd definitely want to test real-world performance before settling on a method of combining the two hashes -- it really will depend on how the dictionary gets used in practice.

Comment: My point is about speed and not correctness. It seems that you're guaranteed to slow down dictionary accesses if you solely ask the class for its hash in your hash method and don't add anything else to the hash. Any reasonable implementation of a dictionary is going to look at hashes to find potential matches before calling isEqual. While your implementation is fine in terms of correctness, it's bound to have a lot of collisions if the consumer of this class has keys with a common class, but different selectors. This implementation appears to trade one bottleneck for another.

Comment: @DavidHodge: OK, I wrote out the full `-hash` method, combining both the class and selector, following the pattern that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

`SEL`s themselves are unique; you could use an `NSValue` and wrap just that:

```
[NSValue valueWithBytes:&selector objCType:@encode(SEL)];
```

Comment: SEL is unique within a class scope but when using multiple classes, it will fail. consider the following code:
    `NSMutableDictionary* dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSNumber* storedValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];

    [dictionary setObject:storedValue forKey:[self getKeyForClass:[classA class] andSelector:@selector(foo)]];

    NSNumber* value = [dictionary objectForKey:[self getKeyForClass:[classB class] andSelector:@selector(foo)]];
    STAssertNil(value, @"Different classes should create different hash");`

Comment: @Tomer: The `SEL`s themselves are unique across the runtime environment of your program. I guess I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish.